# Conversion of List of CustomObject to Guava Table collection with less complexity

Tags: lambda, java-8, guava

I have

```
class CustomObject {
Integer day;
List<InnerObject> innerObjects;
///getter setter

}

class InnerObject {
String id;
List<String> someVal;
//getter setter

}
```

I have a

`List<CustomObject>`

and I want

`Table<String, Integer, List<String>>`

I want table to represent `id (from InnerObject)` -> (`day (from Custom object)`, `List of someVal (from InnerObject)`

Just to make it clean I tweaked names a bit but structure is same as what is expected.

Now how I am doing is

```
final List<CustomObject> objects = ???
final Map<Integer, List<InnerObject>> dayVsInnerObjects = objects.stream()
.collect(toMap(CustomObject::getDay, CustomObject::getInnerObjects));


final Table<String, Integer, List<String>> table = HashBasedTable.create();

 dayVsInnerObjects.forEach((day, innerObjects) -> 
                            innerObjects.forEach(i -> {
                             table.put(i.getId(), day, i.getSomeVal());
            })
);
```

My questions:

1. Is there a better way of doing this? may be a better guava/Collection API that can make it a bit cleaner.
2. Right now table is being populated and it is mutable. can we have a way to make it immutable while creating it.
3. Time complexity if can be reduced here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use [`flatMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-) on the initial stream to get a stream of `Map.Entry<Integer, InnerObject>` (the key being the day) and use these entries to collect directly to a `Table` by means of Guava's [`Tables.toTable`](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/22.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Tables.html#toTable-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Supplier-) built-in collector:

```
Table<String, Integer, List<String>> table = objects.stream()
    .flatMap(custom -> custom.getInnerObjects().stream()
            .map(inner -> new SimpleEntry<>(custom.getDay(), inner)))
    .collect(Tables.toTable(
            entry -> entry.getValue().getId(),
            entry -> entry.getKey(),
            entry -> entry.getValue().getSomeVal(),
            HashBasedTable::create));
```

If you want the `Table` to be immutable, you can use Guava's method [`Tables.unmodifiableTable`](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/22.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Tables.html#unmodifiableTable-com.google.common.collect.Table-):

```
Table<String, Integer, List<String>> unmodifiableTable = Tables.unmodifiableTable(table);
```

Or, if you want to get the unmodifiable `Table` when collecting:

```
Table<String, Integer, List<String>> unmodifiableTable = objects.stream()
    .flatMap(custom -> custom.getInnerObjects().stream()
            .map(inner -> new SimpleEntry<>(custom.getDay(), inner)))
    .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(
            Tables.toTable(
                    entry -> entry.getValue().getId(),
                    entry -> entry.getKey(),
                    entry -> entry.getValue().getSomeVal(),
                    HashBasedTable::create),
            Tables::unmodifiableTable);
```

*Note:* I'm using Guava version 22.0, but as Eugene says in [his comment below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45130592/conversion-of-list-of-customobject-to-guava-table-collection-with-less-complexit/45130885?noredirect=1#comment77249015_45134447), this functionality is available since version 21.0.

As for your questions, I think I've already answered 1 and 2. Regarding 3, no, there's no way to reduce time complexity, as you need to access each `InnerObject` within each `CustomObject`.

Comment: that's pretty cool, I did not know they had such collectors in place, but since `version 21`.

Answer (score 1):

If I am not missing anything you can do a custom collector for that (I don't really understand why you are collecting first to a `Map`):

```
.stream()
.collect((Collector.of(
       HashBasedTable::create, 
       (table, co) -> {
           for (InnerObject io : co.getInnerObjects()) {
                table.put(io.getId(), co.getDay(), io.getSomeVal());
           }
       }, 
       (left, right) -> {
            left.putAll(right);
            return left;
       }));
```

**EDIT** as the other answer is already showing - there are build-in collectors for that already, since `version 21`.

Comment: I added map for readability i.e. breaking into multiple statements. your seems to be working just fine I guess thnx. is there a way i can ignore inner loop also? and would this create many HashBasedTable instance (every right is new HashBasedTable instance?

Comment: @MohammadAdnan you can't ignore the inner loop really - either make it explicit yourself or via some `flatMap` for example... as for the many instanced - that would be created indeed, but only in the parallel processing.

Comment: I wonder why a donwvote here... unless you know that guava 22 is already providing such a collector - in which case a comment would be nice

Comment: @Eugene just to make it clear that I haven't downvoted. Really it doesn't make sense to downvote this answer, as it's the way to go for versions pre 21

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner no worries even if u did